# SRA - Single Page React App - when hosted to GitHub, doesn't load Component which stores 'switch' router code

Tags: reactjs, deployment, single-page-application, github-pages

I have searched everywhere for the answer to this one - and I'm pretty sure it's the way I've laid out my Components in my React app:

In making my Portfolio page in React, I used CREATE REACT APP and after it was finished and functioning perfectly locally, I made the necessary changes to the package.json file for homepage and build, etc. Then when I deployed using Yarn, the host link would open my site - but without one of my components: CONTENT. This component contains a switch that, according to the route, will show the proper content in the body of the page containing that route.

When I click on the navbar, it will then take me to any of the three routes - including a properly displayed home page - but the home will only show after the page first loads and you click on the Navbar.

Why is this? Again - it works locally just fine, but on GH Pages, will only show the Header, NavBar and Footer for the home page on first load.

Thanks,

Rideout

See code below:

Hosted URL on GH Pages:

https://operasinger.github.io/VRideout-Portfolio-React/

Partial Package.json:

```
"homepage": "http://operasinger.github.io/VRideout-Portfolio-React/",
  "name": "vrideout-portfolio-react",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import './Fonts.css';
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import Content from "./components/content";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container-fluid" id="background">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row jumbotronNavy">
            <div className="col-md-4 blue" id="headBlue">
              <h1>Vale Rideout</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 blue" />
            <div className="col-md-4 blue">
              <Navbar />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row" id="content">
            <Content />
          </div>
          <div className="row justify-content-md-center" id="jumbotronFooter">
            <p>&copy; 2018 vale rideout</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      // </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Content Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./about";
import Projects from "./projects";
import Contact from "./contact";

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={About} />
        <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

[This is the home page when visiting the hosted GH Pages URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AMo9.png)

[When refreshed within GH Pages, the full route renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPeA.jpg)

I'm sure this is a very small problem, but it will help me with deploying React apps - as I'm sure it's not a problem native to React.

Thanks!

Rideout

Answer (score 0):

The `BrowserRouter` component matches the entire URL as seen in the browser to your `Route`s. Since the root of your React implementation is not the base (`/`) of the domain, you should add a `baseUrl` property to your `BrowserRouter` to reflect that fact. I think you can do:

`<BrowserRouter baseUrl="/VRideout-Portfolio-React">` but if not just look on the `react-router` docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer not to hard-code the path into the `Router`, you should be able to set a `homepage` inside package.json. Putting this in the package: `"homepage": "https://operasinger.github.io/VRideout-Portfolio-React/"` will prefix the paths with `/VRideout-Portfolio-React` when you run `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

Actually [create-react-app docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#notes-on-client-side-routing) covers this pretty well.

I've also noticed, that you are using Router component (`BrowserRouter` in your example) incorrectly. It should be above all of Routing configuration and `Link`s in jsx tree. This is done to inject context, which will be used by all children of the `Router` component (even deeply nested).

---

#### TL;DR

Just use `<HashRouter>` as the root component of your Application.

Comment: Thanks - still just a beginner, but I appreciate this one - worked like a charm.

Comment: Well.... update: charm? yes - I was able to get the homepage to render correctly, but it disabled all other Routes - using either ROUTE or LINK - even when used with every possible and conceivable permutation of:

    {`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} 

or

    basename={"my-subdirectory-name"}

And this is with my homepage set in Package.json and the name listed as well. I've tried every permutation and sometimes it renders as before - with no CONTENT app in the body - and sometimes the full homepage renders. Now though, no links are active. The inconsistency bothers me as well.

Comment: @VRideout take a look at https://dsimushkin.github.io/react-draggable-hoc/, you can find source files at https://github.com/dsimushkin/react-draggable-hoc/tree/master/demo. It's implemented with typescript, but I believe, you can figure that out